# Copying a picturebox over into a panel (VB.net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, controls

I have been doing some research and havent found out how to do this:

I have a list of pictures inside a Panel and was wondering if when I click one of the pictures, it puts the selected image inside another panel for something. I would also like a way to remove it via a button. Could this be possible? I have yet to find a way how.

Comment: How can a Panel have a list? Can you show some code?

Comment: When I say list, i ment a whole bunch of pictures

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if i understood... you can set `visible = false` the clicked image, and load the same BMP/PNG to the image on the second panel and set to it `visible = true`(do this in the image click event), is just a trick, you can do alot of things just "have imagination".